# Are the agents released when the pipeline is waiting for approval?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are experimenting with the [Azure Pipelines checks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEDcE.png) feature and noticed that the process never ends unless we manually approve all stages.
We are not planning to approve all stages (some stages might take weeks to get approved or some will be never approved) because we don't want to promote every single build to production.
Is this an expected behavior? Are the agents released during the wait period?

See image below as en example. As you can see, we did not approve the 3rd stage but the timer keeps increasing.

[image: Example execution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an expected behavior?

The answer for this question is Yes. This is a expected behavior. The **Approve** will waiting until it be approved/rejected or expired by the the Timeout setting:

[image]

> Are the agents released during the wait period?

In fact, after the previous stage job finished. The agent has been released. And during the period of waiting for approve, it will not possess this agent. As you can see the pic shown below:

[image]

I have 2 stages in release. After stage1 job finished and waiting for stage2's pre-approve, the agent has been released and does not be possessed by the stage2. The agent will be used again until you approve this stage and job begin running. So, for waiting approval, you don't need worry about the agent will be possessed.